# Spec flow parallel execution with NUnit + .net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nunit

is .net core still not enabled for NUnit parallel test execution.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

NUnit parallel test execution is enabled for .Net Core for a while now https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2542